# java conditional operator,why following code is giving output as true?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

```
class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        boolean a = false;
        boolean b = true;

        if (a && a || b) {
            System.out.println(true);
        }
    }
} //--why it always true????o/p is true but why??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Order of operations.**

`&&` has higher precedence than `||` and therefore is evaluated *first*.  Your `if` condition can be rewritten as follows:

```
(a && a) || b
(false && false) || true
false || true
true
```

This condition will always be `false || true` which is always `true` for the conditions you listed.

Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for an official table from Oracle which lists the precedence of all operators.

Comment: Because the precedence of `&&` vs `||` is often misunderstood, it's a good idea to *always* use explicit parenthesis when mixing `&&` and `||`. That way it can never go wrong.

Comment: @Andreas I strongly agree with you, and taking your advice also results in code which is easier to read and maintain (and this is true in _every_ language).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has the equivalence to this statement ::

*If A is true or B is true the statement is true*

Since B is set to true your statement is true. Also, there is no need to test A twice so instead of doing

```
(a && a || b) // old 
(a || b) //new
```

`&&` has a higher order of operation then `||` so it is evaluated first.
To work around this you can use braces

```
if( a && ( a || b )) //tests as i believe you wanted although its redundent
```

Comment: `a && (a || b)` is equivalent to just `a`, except that `b` is evaluated if `a` is true, which makes a difference if `b` is a method call with side effects.

Comment: note the comment beside the statement, that appeared to be the way he wanted his statements order to go, just a simple order of operations example

Answer (score 0):

```
a && a || b :
    a && a => false && false => false
    false || b => false || true => true
```

If there had been parens to change the operator precedence:

```
a && (a||b) :
    a || b => false || true => true
    a && true => false && true => false
```

then the result would be different.

Moral: if you are unsure of the precedence use parens so you are sure.

Comment: I think parentheses should _always_ be used when mixing `&&` and `||`.  There is one language, Ada, that required this (it uses the keywords `and then` and `or else` instead of `&&` and `||`).  It's too bad that idea (requiring parentheses) didn't catch on.  It would prevent lots of problems like this one.

Answer (score 0):

A = False
B = True

A && A (False && False) = False 
( A && A(False) )   ||  B (True) = True

Your last expression is `False || True = True`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the AND(&&) operator is solved first then the OR(||) operator.
run

```
  if (b||a&&a) {

        System.out.println(true);
    }
```

it will give you true again because && is calculated first.